# Remove multiple blanks with a single blank in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have DataFrame created with HiveContext where one of the columns hold records like:

```
text1        text2
```

We want the in between spaces between the 2 texts to be replaced with a single text and get final output as :

```
text1 text2
```

Ho can we achieve that in Spark SQL? Note we are using Hive Context, registering temp table and writing SQL queries over it.

Comment: I think you mean via HiveContext

Comment: Column holding a record?

Comment: Use trim first and then concatinate bot adding space in between

Comment: better approach below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even better that I have now been enlightened by a real expert. It's simpler in fact:

```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
// val myUDf = udf((s:String) => Array(s.trim.replaceAll(" +", " ")))
   val myUDf = udf((s:String) => s.trim.replaceAll("\\s+", " ")) // <-- no Array(...)
// Then there is no need to play with columns excessively:

   val data = List("i  like    cheese", "  the dog runs   ", "text111111   text2222222")
   val df = data.toDF("val")
   df.show()

   val new_df = df.withColumn("new_val", myUDf(col("val")))
   new_df.show
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val myUDf = udf((s:String) => Array(s.trim.replaceAll(" +", " ")))
//error: object java.lang.String is not a value --> use Array

val data = List("i  like    cheese", "  the dog runs   ", "text111111   text2222222")
val df = data.toDF("val")
df.show()

val new_df = df
  .withColumn("udfResult",myUDf(col("val")))
  .withColumn("new_val", col("udfResult")(0))
  .drop("udfResult")
new_df.show
```

Output on Databricks

```
+--------------------+
|                 val|
+--------------------+
|   i  like    cheese|
|     the dog runs   |
|text111111   text...|
+--------------------+

+--------------------+--------------------+
|                 val|             new_val|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|   i  like    cheese|       i like cheese|
|     the dog runs   |        the dog runs|
|text111111   text...|text111111 text22...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

just do in spark.sql

regexp_replace( COLUMN, ' +', ' ')

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#regexp_replace

check it:

```
spark.sql("""
    select regexp_replace(col1, ' +', ' ') as col2
    from (
        select 'text1        text2     text3' as col1
    )
""").show(20,False)
```

output

```
+-----------------+
|col2             |
+-----------------+
|text1 text2 text3|
+-----------------+
```